# How to click on an element when the tag is ::before?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm using Selenium trying to click a button on the page, but when I select the element in the Code Inspection of the page it is in a `::before` tag that doesn't give an option to copy the `xpath`

How do I get the `xpath` of this element to click?

I tried to get the `xpath` of tags close and related to the button I need to click, but without success.

Comment: Share HTML code sample for the button. And don't mind the `::before` node. This CSS pseudo-node definitely cannot contain a button or any other node. Also I don't recommend to use browser XPath generators.

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this: try to click on the parent of this element

you do not provide the HTML code，So I can only provide you with one reference

```
drive.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xxxx"]/..').click()
```